# Object following curve distortion

Tags: modeling

I am trying to create a wall with planks set at a certain angle. With the Array and Curve/Nurbs i am trying to follow the Curve. For some reason the planks direction distorts in all directions. Can anyone help me creating this? Added are some pics for reference like the shape of the Curve, the result in Blender and an example of what is should become.
[image: This is the Curve.]
This is the Curve (topview).
[image: This is my Blender result]
This is my Blender result...
[image: This is what is should be]
This is what is should become when finished.

Comment: Your planks need subdivisions, otherwise there is nothing to bend

Comment: Thanks!!! That was it! Sometimes it can be so easy... :\